# SQL - combining DISTINCT and INNER JOIN and COUNT(CASE WHEN)

Tags: sql, distinct, case, inner-join

I have SQL which return me correct result.

```
select accounts.name, count( case when ((( estimated_start_date<='2013-01-01' 
and project.status='closed')

or ( estimated_start_date<='2013-01-01' and project.status='open' 
and estimated_end_date>='2013-04-01')))
then 1 else null end) as Number

from project

inner join project_cstm on project.id=project_cstm.id_c
inner join accounts on project_cstm.account_id_c=accounts.id

group by accounts.name
```

I returns me good result:

On example:

```
Telenor 5
Telecom 3
```

Now I want to add new field `BOOKED_DATE` in `WHERE` clause to restrict number of projects only with some projects tasks created in in that interval. So I do INNER JOIN with table `inner join project_task` and results should be smaller but instead I am getting as result these huge numbers.Don not know how to combine it.

Thanks for help

```
Telenor 150
Telecom 980

select accounts.name, count( case when ((( estimated_start_date<='2013-01-01' 
and project.status='closed')

or ( estimated_start_date<='2013-01-01' and project.status='open' 
and estimated_end_date>='2013-04-01')))
then 1 else null end) as Number

from project

inner join project_cstm on project.id=project_cstm.id_c
inner join accounts on project_cstm.account_id_c=accounts.id
inner join project_task on project_task.project_id=project.id
where booked_date>'2013-01-01' and booked_date<'2015-01-01'
group by accounts.name
```

Because of rows in table PROJECT_TASK I am getting HUGE results which are far from correct. How to restrict that? I tried putting `... count(distinct case when ...` but than result is always 1.

So I must somehow restrict this values but instead of that I am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are counting 1 for each task of your project, that's why you have this much.
For each project, you need to increment your count only 1 time.

You want to count the distinct projet, so instead of counting only 1's, count distinct project id's:

```
select accounts.name
     , count( distinct  -- here distinct
        case when ((( estimated_start_date<='2013-01-01' and project.status='closed')
                 or ( estimated_start_date<='2013-01-01' and project.status='open' and estimated_end_date>='2013-04-01')))
        then project.id -- here project id
        else null 
        end) as Number
from project
    inner join project_cstm 
        on project.id=project_cstm.id_c
    inner join accounts 
        on project_cstm.account_id_c=accounts.id
    inner join project_task 
        on project_task.project_id=project.id
where booked_date>'2013-01-01' 
and booked_date<'2015-01-01'
group by accounts.name
```

Comment: thank you. I was so close but I couldn't make without you. All the best

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test your query, but I think you should use something like this:

```
select accounts.name, count(DISTINCT project.id) as Number
from project   
  inner join project_cstm on project.id=project_cstm.id_c
  inner join accounts on project_cstm.account_id_c=accounts.id
  inner join project_task on project_task.project_id=project.id
where
  (booked_date>'2013-01-01' and booked_date<'2015-01-01')
  AND ((estimated_start_date<='2013-01-01' and project.status='closed')
      OR
       (estimated_start_date<='2013-01-01'
        and project.status='open'
        and estimated_end_date>='2013-04-01'))
group by accounts.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your joining table project_task might have duplicates in column 'project_id'